# Laravel save model with relationship at once

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an Order with many Products.

I'm then observing Order created event, and triggering an order confirmation email once saved.

The problem I'm having is I have to do `$order->products()->saveMany($products)` after I have saved the `$order` object. Which means the confirmation email is being sent before saving its related products, so calling`$order->products()` in the email template is empty.

It feels like i'm missing something here, is there no way to pass the products into the first `$order->save()` so the whole order is created at once.

Comment: what if you observe the products created event?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is impossible since the order **has** to be created before you can attach products (at least for auto-incrementing primary keys).

Personally, I would add a method to attach the products (`$order->setProducts($products)`) which attaches them and also fires off the mail. You could even check the [`wasRecentlyCreated`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#property_wasRecentlyCreated) property to make sure the mail isn't sent if you happen to call that method again for an existing order.

> `bool`    `$wasRecentlyCreated`   Indicates if the model was inserted during the current request lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

First

```
$order->save()
```

And then

```
$order->products()->saveMany($products)
```

the last thing you should do:

```
//email sending codes
```